# Drag and drop image upload

Tags: images, upload

Looking for an app that will allow me to drag and drop an image file onto it's icon and have it automatically uploaded to an associated image hosting site. Other requirements:

- Upon successful upload I am given a url to the image
- Image host should not convert or re-size the file (I mainly deal with transparent png images which look like crap when converted to jpeg)
- Site needs to allow hot linking.
- Site should keep the image for a minimum of 90 days.

Anything out there like this or am I just SOL ?

Answer (score 0):

[Rightload](http://rightload.org/) is very good and you don't even have to drag...

> Rightload is a small program that allows you to quickly upload files
>   directly from a Windows folder to your server. Instead of using
>   complicated software just to upload a few pictures, you just
>   right-click on the files, select the server and target folder and
>   Rightload will do the rest for you.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure about the other host, but tinypic requires a captcha to upload, does this application somehow bypass that requirement ?

Comment: Just read the forums for the above app and tinypic support is broken so no go there.

Answer (score 0):

Well, why don't you use Dropbox? Just create a shortcut to your Dropbox public folder, put it anywhere you want and drag and drop your files there. With [Dropbox Linker](http://dropboxlinker.codeplex.com/) you can get your link in the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

The ImageShack Uploader supports drag and drop, direct links, no resizing of files, and your files will be hosted indefinitely.

Here's a link: [ImageShack Uploader](http://imageshack.us/content.php?page=uploader)